# How do you pass the elements from a one-dimensional array to a two dimensional array

Tags: java

I am trying to figure out how to print the elements of an array with 10 elements per line. Every time I think I have come up with a solution there is some part of the code that we haven't studied yet. So I hit a dead end. I thought about passing the element of my one dimensional array to a two-dimensional array with 10 elements per row then printing the individual rows. But I dont' know how to pass the elements form the one dimensional array to the two dimensional array.

```
import java.util.*;

public class myFirstArray
{

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      double alpha[] = new double[50];


      for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) 

         if (i < 25)
            alpha[i] = i * i;

         else 
            alpha[i] = i * 3;

      for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++)

          // prints all 50 elements on one line
          System.out.print (alpha[i] + ", ");

   }

}
```

Comment: Do you only want to print ten elements per line?

Comment: Yes, it is driving me nuts. I have tried a while loop and if...else to print only the first 10. I figured if I could get it to only print the first 10 then I'd figure it out from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a two-dimensional array for this. Simply print a new line when `i = 0 (mod 10)` to split up the output into lines of 10 numbers each.

You might need to modify the way you deal with commas a bit, depending on your output specifications, but in general the code will look like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < alpha.length; i++) {
    if(i != 0 && i % 10 == 0) {
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.print(alpha[i] + ", ");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried so many different things but I didn't think of that! Awesome! It worked like a charm!

Comment: A very simple illustration of a fundamental principle in software: the internal representation of data needs not be constrained by the way it is viewed externally. :-)